# Change default zoom on Android Studio preview window

Tags: android-studio

I was wondering if is possible to change the default zoom of the preview window.
For me, it's always at 22% and every single time I change the window, it goes back to 22%. I prefer at 50% so I can see everything well.

[image]

Comment: Did u find the answer?

Comment: @Nuhman Can't remember now. Stopped using this IDE as soon as I could. But I think there may be a tweak under *preferences*. (Not 100% sure)

Comment: may I ask which IDE you changed to?

Comment: @Nuhman I'm learning React and using VSCODE text editor.

Comment: your first comment sounded like you stopped using Android Studio and switched to some other IDE for android dev. Hence the question. Ok cool.

Answer (score 0):

'a bit late' but maybe smbd have the same problem

File -> Settings -> Appearance -> Window options(Widescreen tool window layout)

That's all:)